# Personalized Offer Solution Template on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to work on the personalized offer solution on Azure from [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-ai-personalized-offers)

I followed the manual deployment guide step by step (3 times) and I always end up facing the same error when I try to run the function `SeedDocumentDB`. Seems like I am having issues with the frameworks.  I am very keen to leverage this architecture for lab project, would really appreciate if someone could assist me in seeing how I could possibly troubleshoot this?

The error that I keep facing is in this picture:

[image: 500 Error]

Comment: As stated in the github page

"See the Manual Deployment Guide folder for a full set of instructions on how to put together and deploy a Personalized Offers solution using Azure services. For technical problems or questions about deploying this solution, please post in the issues tab of the repository."

Maybe you should ask this in the issues tab for that github repository instead?

Comment: Hi Andreas, thank you for the prompt reply. I tried to post it in github repo and even tried to contact the author of this guide but with no chance. This is an urgent matter and would really want to know how to fix it asap.